# max-values-per-tag limit exceeded Why getting error on TAG KEY ip_address only?

Tags: influxdb

**InfluxDB version 1.3.1**
May be I couldn't fully understand meaning of "max-values-per-tag".

I am getting error

```
HTTP Code 400 {"error":"partial write: max-values-per-tag limit exceeded (100000/100000): measurement=\"uptime\" tag=\"ip_address\" value=\"172.10.10.01\" dropped=1"}
```

I'm inserting many rows (150k every 15 min, 7 days retention) like this. Along with ip_address I have TAG KEYS like state, host which contains values such as MH, GJ, KA and MH0001, GJ0001, KA0001

But the error which I am getting is specific about ip_address only.

Why not on state or host ?

I tried to get rid of this error by changing max-values-per-tag = 0 in config
still getting this error. does it require restart influxdb server ?

or

If I remove ip_address from TAG will it be helpful to get rid of this error ?